# Why NSMutableDictionary won't write to file

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift3

Forgive the mixing of legacy classes and Swift 3, but why doesn't this work?

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let documents = paths[0] as String
let path = documents.appending("/SomeData.plist")
let url : URL = URL.init(string: path)!

let sampleDict : NSMutableDictionary = ["name" : "somebody", "age" : "30 ", "food" : "taco"]

let manager = FileManager.default
if (manager.fileExists(atPath: url.absoluteString)) {

      sampleDict.write(to: url, atomically: true)

} else {

      manager.createFile(atPath: url.absoluteString, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
      sampleDict.write(to: url, atomically: true)
}
```

The file is created at the path, but writing the contents of the dictionary fails every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLs in the file system **must** be created with

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
```

The URL is always non optional.

And a file system URL must be checked with

```
if (manager.fileExists(atPath: url.path)) {...
```

`URL(string:` (**no init**) and `.absoluteString` are related to URLs with a different scheme as `file` for example `http` or `ftp`

Don't annotate types unless the compiler really needs it, for example

```
let sampleDict = ["name" : "somebody", "age" : "30 ", "food" : "taco"]
```

If you want a mutable dictionary use `var` rather than `let`

PS: Modern syntax

```
let manager = FileManager.default
let documentURL = try! manager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let url = documentURL.appendingPathComponent("SomeData.plist")
let sampleDict = ["name" : "somebody", "age" : "30 ", "food" : "taco"]
do {
  let data = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: sampleDict, format: .xml, options: 0)
  try data.write(to: url)
} catch let error as NSError {
  print(error)
}
```

Explicitly creating a new file is not needed.

Comment: Thank you. The issue here was 'fileURLWithPath'. The serialization insights are useful, the snippet I shared is not optimized, but in usage is writing a NSMutableDict coming from legacy code, the dict I shared was a stand-in with the same type.